# Encontrar commit no qual ficheiro foi apagado

Tags: git

Tenho um projeto no Git. Preciso reaver um ficheiro que foi apagado há vários meses.

Fosse algo que estivesse agora no repositório seria trivial encontrá-lo, ver seu histórico e alterações. Mas como é algo que foi removido, estou com dificuldade para obter a última versão do ficheiro anterior a sua exclusão.

Por falta de alternativa melhor, penso em fazer uma busca binária nos *commits*... Mas serei muito grato (e creio que muitos outros também o serão) se indicarem forma mais eficiente de encontrar o *commit* no qual algo que foi removido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você sabe o caminho do arquivo que foi excluído, use:

```
git log --all -- <arquivo>
```

Senão, use:

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete
```

Referência: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203515/how-to-locate-a-deleted-file-in-the-commit-history).